# Why are there two formulas for variance of random variables?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, random-variables, intuition, variance

I'm using an introductory statistics textbook and it mentioned this:

> Definition: If $X$ is a random variable with mean $E(X)  = \mu$, then the variance  of $X$ is defined by $Var(X) = E((X−\mu)^2)$.

I thought the formula for the variance of X was: $$Var(X) = \sum_{i=1}^n p_i \cdot (x_i - μ)^2$$

How come it's different?

Comment: If X is discrete then these are the same, which is a special case of the "law of the unconscious statistician".

Comment: How are they the same @Ian?

Comment: E[X] - the expectancy of X means summing all possible values of $x\in D$ times the probability of those values to show.
therefore : if E[X] = $\sum_{i=0}^n{p_i\times x_i}$ then it's exactly the same for the value of sqared distance of a certain x from the Mean level $\mu$

Comment: A Discrete Random Variables is different (in nature and associated laws) from Continuous Random Variable. As a result the formula for calculating the variance is difference. For simple discussion see:http://www.henry.k12.ga.us/ugh/apstat/chapternotes/7supplement.html

Comment: $\newcommand{\E}{\Bbb{E}}$Remember, $\E[f(X)] =\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}p_i f(x_i)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X$ is discrete then $E(X)=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\cdot f(x_i)$. Now let $y_i=(x_i-\mu)^2$. The expected value of $Y$ is $E(Y)=\sum_{i=1}^n  (x_i-\mu)^2\cdot f(x_i)$

$$=\sum_{i=1}^n  x_i^2\cdot f(x_i)-2\cdot \mu\cdot \underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i f(x_i)}_{=\mu}+\mu^2 \underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i)}_{=1}$$

$$=\sum_{i=1}^n  x_i^2\cdot f(x_i)-\mu^2=Var(X)=E[(X-\mu)^2]$$